# DB insertion and Load Tableview approach

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsnotificationcenter

I have written API manager class to call API and insert that data into multiple table in sqlite database.

Until now I have add a Notifier in my API manager class, in which once all the data is added, I have call the notifier and reload my tableview.

Now is there better approach then notifier to reload tableview once data insert from API to local db finishes at background?

**Here is the flow.**

**FirstViewController.m** 
- Contain Tableview that shows data according to fetch from local database.

- Reload tabliew after fetch local database at the NOTIFIER call.

**API Manager Class**

- API Call using API manager class
- API response -> insert / update /delete data on multiple table  (a lot of entries ) according to need and at the end of insert / update / delete complete notifier is fire

**Expect** : Better Approach then notifier 
Update UITableview , without notifier Response

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a normal implementation,
as you need to notify your UI, when your process has finished.
also imaging maybe you have some error during your Insert, Delete, Update so you should deal with them and once you finish the process inform your UI
another option is used `NSFetchResultController` which Integrated with your CoreData.